# Yii2 - Trying to get property of non-object with relations

Tags: php, yii2, relationship, yii2-advanced-app, dataprovider

views/search.php

```
<?php foreach($dataProvider->getModels() as $call){ ?>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td><?=$call->created?></td>
    <td><?=$call->call_datetime?></td>
    <td><?=$call->call_from?></td>
    <td><?=$call->call_to?></td>
    <td><?=$call->duration?></td>
    <td><?=$call->call_type?></td>
    <td><?=$call->extension?></td>
   <td><?=$call->callRecFiles->fname?></td> 
</tr>
</tbody>
<?php } ?>
```

relation in models/Call.php

```
 public function getCallRecFiles()
{
    return $this->hasOne(CallRecording::className(), ['callref' => 'callref']);
}
```

Controller actionSearch

```
public function actionSearch($id)
{
    $cust = new Customer();
    Yii::$app->user->identity->getId();
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Call::find()
            ->with('customer', 'callRecFiles') // eager loading relations 'customer' & 'callRecFiles' 
            ->where(['custref' => $id])
            ->limit(10),
        'pagination' => false, // defaults to true | when true '->limit()' is automatically handled
    ]);
    return $this->render('search',[
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'cust' => $cust,
    ]);
}
```

What am i doing wrong here or missing? I have browsed other similar questions however all seem to be involving widgets or file input. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: On which model->field  you  have this error?

Comment: Instead of printing them out like that, run a `foreach()` with just `var_dump($call)` and see if the attribute exists. I would guess that it is the `callRecFiles` that gives you the error, see if it exists. You could also try `if(isset($call->callRecFiles) echo $call->callRecFiles->fname`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two places where you can have error `Trying to get property of non-object`.

First is here:

```
<td><?=$call->callRecFiles->fname?></td>
```

To avoid it, you should use `if` statement:

```
<td><?= $call->callRecFiles ? $call->callRecFiles->fname : null ?></td>
```

Second is here:

```
Yii::$app->user->identity->getId();
```

If there's no access controll rule in your controller, an unlogged user can access this action and search method, so you don't have `identity` of user until he logs in. To avoid it, you should add `behaviors` to your controller:

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::class,
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow'         => true,
                    'roles'         => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

It will require user to log in before accessing your actions in this controller.

By the way, you are not using at all this code:

```
Yii::$app->user->identity->getId();
```

So removing it is also a solution.

Comment: Thank you @Yupik very detailed answer. I forgot to put it in the question but the error was coming from `<td><?=$call->callRecFiles->fname?></td>`